# Run a span across process boundaries in opentracing-java

Tags: java, opentracing

Process A puts a job in a queue, process B picks it up and runs it. I would like my spans to look like

```
--start------------------------
            ---pick-and-run----
```

so that the span originating from process A finishes in process B. With these 2 spans the child one tells me how long did the job run whereas the toplevel tells me how long did it run+wait.

Looking through the [opentracing-java API](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.opentracing/opentracing-api/0.33.0) I see the `Tracer` can `extract` a `SpanContext` and that the `Tracer` can `activate` a `Span`. I see no way to turn the `SpanContext` into a `Span` though. Is there a way to do this? Or is this a misuse?